Shower glass doors vibrating/shaking when closing
Hope someone can shine a light on this.
Door is frameless glass, rollers at the TOP. Problem started after the rollers were replaced by new ones. Purchased good quality ZAMAC rollers just like the previous ones (avoided the plastic ones). Door started to vibrate/shake during the closing process, more or less when the rear roller approaches the middle of the rail.
List of things I already did:

Tracks were cleaned and are pristine.
I tried lubricating the tracks with silicone grease. Did nothing. Removed it.
Door has the plastic aligner in the bottom. It is tuned to the most firm (more friction) setting. tried with the loose setting. No difference.
Front roller was tuned to either high, medium or low positions. No effect. And the same with the rear roller. Nothing.
A combination of high/low and many others were tried between the two rollers (both high, both down, one high/mid, other mid/high, etc,etc,etc). Nothing improved.
No matter what I do the door vibrates when halfway closing the door. If I close it very fast, it does not vibrate. If I close slower, it vibrates even more.

Pulling my hair here.
I am suspecting of the roller quality.
Sound of door.
SOUND of door

EDIT: today I noticed (actually found the old discarded rollers in my box of stuff) that the previous rollers were not made of Zamac (metallic). They had a plastic frame (yellow roller, black plastic body, probably nylon). I will try to buy a pair of them and try. Maybe they dampened the vibration somehow? Will report.
CONFIRMED: Today arrived the Nylon/Poliacetal (polyoxymethylene - POM) rollers, which matched the original. I thought the metallic/zamaz would be of better quality but I guess for my configuration the Nylon ones are more adequate. Vibration immediately disappeared using the black/yellow rollers. Living and learning. I used these ones: https://i.imgur.com/GrW5N1W.png

Due to the location it happens, #1 and #3 are the main suspects.  Bearings in the rollers are second.

Rollers out of round?

Edited the text and here is the solution: bought a pair of black/yellow POM+Nylon rollers. Vibration immediately disappeared.

